# What's the Proper Way to Describe a Multidimensional Object?

Tags: javascript, json, terminology

PHP has multidimensional arrays, that is, an array containing multiple arrays.

In JavaScript, how would one call an object containing multiple objects? A multidimensional object? Or does it have its own lingo?

What about JSON? Is the term multidimensional JSON proper?

Comment: nested object? you won't offend you object by calling it the wrong name, so don't worry too much about it :)

Comment: Javascript has "multidimensional" arrays as well. `var arr = [ [2, 5], [3, 7] ]; console.log(arr[0][1]); // 5`

Comment: Strictly speaking, a multidimensional arrays is not the same as an array of arrays. When talking about data structures, people often use the term "nested".

Comment: http://blog.a-la-russe.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Matroschka-50-Puppen1.jpg

Comment: @connexo that's a nice analogy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object containing multiple objects is just an object. You can call it a multidimensional object (or a nested object), it's just an object inside another object.

As for [JSON](http://www.json.org/), it's an object notation for representing objects:

> JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange
>   format. It is easy for humans to read and write. It is easy for
>   machines to parse and generate. It is based on a subset of the
>   JavaScript Programming Language, Standard ECMA-262 3rd Edition -
>   December 1999.